# How to implement django cms page versioning?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-cms

I am using django-cms 3.5.2
I am unable to find any plugins which support page versioning.

There is plugin on github:
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-versioning

But I am not sure if it is published and ready to use.
Any references?

Comment: Well the GitHub page has [*releases*](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-versioning/releases) so that means it is to some extent"ready to use" (well normally one does not release if it is still something that is not working at all).

Comment: Yes but it says "you have a django CMS 4.0 (or higher)" which is not released yet. Also installation of this plugin is not working(pip install djangocms-versioning).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this fits your needs, if you are looking for a history of your pages/content in the cms backend, this might be the way to go: [djangocms-history](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-history).

> django CMS History is an addon application to provide undo/redo
>   functionality in django CMS, by maintaining content history.

Comment: No, its more like redo undo feature in page draft mode.